# PHP - How Get text before tag By preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

How can I get ("TEXT") by preg_match

```
$Text ='<input value="AAA" name="A1"> <input value="BBB" name="A2"> <input value="TEXT" name="A3">';

preg_match('!<input value="(.*?)" name="A3">!', $Text, $Word);

echo $Word[1];  //AAA" name="A1"> <input value="BBB" name="A2"> <input value="TEXT
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: replace `.*` by `[^"]*` which means *not `"`*

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `.*?` part into a negated character class.

```
"([^"]*)"
```

However, you can utilize [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to achieve this as well.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
     <input value="AAA" name="A1">
     <input value="BBB" name="A2">
     <input value="TEXT" name="A3">
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$match = $xpath->query('//input[@name="A3"]');

echo $match->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: *Lingo nitpick*: DOM isn't a parser. The parser is libxml. DOM is just a traversal API for the node tree.

Answer (score 1):

This simple:

https://regex101.com/r/tI8vQ1/1

```
/<input value="(\w*)" name="A3">/
```